# Match class that implements inteface and method with specified return type

Tags: javaagents, byte-buddy

I wonder if it is possible to write byte-buddy java-agent which will find in project classes that implement specified interface, and match, in those classes, methods that return also specified type ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. You can apply the agent builder for this:

```
new AgentBuilder.Default()
  .type(ElementMatchers.isSubTypeOf(YourInterface.class))
  .transform((builder, type, cl, module) ->
    builder.method(returns(YourReturnType.class)).intercept( ... )
  ).installOn(inst);
```